Issue with 'flutter_blue_plus' library: Unable to scan mobile Bluetooth devices, despite successful scanning of printers and ear pods
I am working on a Flutter project where I'm using the flutter_blue_plus library version 1.32.8 to handle Bluetooth functionality. However, I'm encountering an issue where the library is not scanning mobile Bluetooth devices (such as smartphones and tablets), even though it successfully scans other Bluetooth devices like printers and earpods.
I have implemented the scanning functionality according to the documentation provided by flutter_blue_plus, and it works fine for certain types of Bluetooth peripherals but fails to detect mobile devices. This issue is critical for my project as it requires the ability to connect with various Bluetooth devices, including smartphones.
I have ensured that Bluetooth permissions are correctly set in the AndroidManifest.xml file and that the necessary permissions are requested at runtime in my Flutter application. Despite these precautions, I still cannot detect mobile devices via Bluetooth scanning.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with flutter_blue_plus or another Flutter Bluetooth library? Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot or resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.


This might be a simple issue: Are you sure that the phones and tablets are advertising? Advertisements are needed for the devices to be found. Phones and tablets usually do not advertise on their own, there needs to be an app that wants to accept connections. Please try to use a generic BLE exploration tool such as nRF Connect t0 scan for these devices. I assume you get the same result
